# Debouncing edit bumps

Tags: feature-request, edits, bump

My opt-out of bumping checkbox for edits was predictably not well received [Support Sage-ing edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/425428/11998382). So I'm having a second go.

### What about an opt-in to a debounce for your edit bumps?

Once you've posted and have spotted something incorrect you want to update it immediately so that all new viewers see something that is correct. However, this may result in many bumps (as these rushed edits tend to contain typos).

But if the bump was debounced, then new views would see the correct thing. And then you could make subsequent edits (within a time period) without repeated bumping.

IMO Stack Overflow is totally unreasonable and expects question askers to know what they are doing. No. Question askers should be enabled to make the best question they can while not knowing what they are doing. I don't think SO is understanding enough of people who don't understand the subject matter. Not understanding the subject matter is not the same as not knowing how to ask a question.

Also you can just put any feature that can be abused behind a reputation barrier.

Comment: on second thought, the implementation might be too complex to make it worth it

Comment: There is already a 5 minute edit grace period for all users with >= 10 reputation. The user can make multiple edits in that time, which all replace the user's prior edit. Each such edit does, however, send out a new WebSocket notification of the edit, so does bump the question, but the timestamp of the post doesn't change. So, in effect, the debouncing you're requesting already exists.

Answer (score 4):

These seem to be the ideas in conflict here:

- Old posts should get edited for quality improvements, especially if they're already highly upvoted, commonly used as duplicate targets, or otherwise important
- All edits need to be reviewed in case of quality loss (ranging from vandalism to inappropriate bikeshedding), even from established users
- Frequently "bumping" posts can be annoying, as it draws attention away from new questions and may put undue emphasis on specific topics (for example if an editor is going through a niche tag)
- For edits that *aren't* from 2k+ users, the review queue gets invoked and everyone hates that

How about if we had an easy way to *search for recently edited posts* (along with filtering by tag etc.), so that it wouldn't be necessary to bump or queue those posts for them to get attention? That is, let people wearing the curator hat "pull" those posts, rather than trying to "push" them?